# Using control Height & Grid.RowSpan together

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I've got some XAML like this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding OverrideEntityList}" Margin="5" Height="200" Width="250" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GeometryType}" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Grid x:Name="AddLineGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Length:" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OverrideLength}" Width="50" Margin="5"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Angle:" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OverrideAngle}" Width="50" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="AddArcGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Diameter:" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OverrideLength}" Width="50" Margin="5"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Angle:" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OverrideAngle}" Width="50" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddOverrideEntityCommand}" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to get the ListBox to fill the whole column, but only be a certain height (because I don't want it to expand when items are added - just the scrollbar to appear).

The XAML designer in Visual Studio shows me what I would expect:
[image: XAML Designer]

But the resulting view when I build my program doesn't seem to respect the Grid.RowSpan of the ListBox:

[image: View in program]

Is there a conflict between setting the Height on the ListBox along with the Grid.RowSpan? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a conflict between setting the Height on the ListBox along with the Grid.RowSpan? Or is there something else I'm missing?

The ListView does span all 3 rows but since it only has a height of 200 and the height of the window is larger than this, it naturally won't be able to fill the entire column from top to bottom.

You should set the height of the `ListView` to the same height as the window for this to happen. You can do this initially using a `OneTime` binding:

```
<ListBox Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding OverrideEntityList}" Margin="5" Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneTime}" Width="250" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Comment: I just moved the `Height="200"` property to the Grid rather than the ListBox and that seemed to solve the problem (still don't know why the XAML Designer was showing me one thing, but the actual view was showing me another)

Comment: Perhsps the design height of the window is different than the actual height at runtime. But you should never trust the designer. It is the behaviour you experience at runtime that matters. The designer can be disabled altogether :)